# Hosting Requirement for an Online Journal and Advice

Tags: hosting, journal

I am developing an application that will collect journals from academicians, review it, and publish it on the site for the world to see. There would also be a blog, forum, and some form of social network.

Users would be allowed to submit documents, photos, and video. I am estimating that on an average a user will use up 1gb a year and we expect to host about 350 users on the site during the first year.

What hosting technology and requirements do you think i may need? Please are there any other considerations i should take into account?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say 1GB per year per user is incredibly conservative.  Academic papers can get *huge*.  Especially in PDF format.

I think that a freemium model of 1GB per year, with paid-for addons is a better idea.

Anyway.  You want to build the entire application in whatever language you're most experienced in, then figure out the hosting requirements from that.

I suggest you take a look at hosting on AWS, deployment with [AWS OpsWorks](http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/).

AWS is pretty much the most flexible cloud-based hosting service, with the highest amount of community information available, and the easiest learning curve.